# Mapreduce in mongodb ruby native driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using native ruby driver for mongodb.I want to perform map reduce function with that and i tried given as per this link [here](https://gist.github.com/343632/8c67eda6260bcf615b4705064d5c0378e91ab32b).

I got the error state's `undefined method last for nil:NilClass`

The code i tried is as

```
def self.mapreduce
    begin
    # remove old decoments
    DBEngine.remove_alldocuments(COLLECTION_MAPREDUCE)
    # sample collection insertion to perform map reduce function
    3.times do |ctr|
    document = {
    "cust_id" => "A12",
    "amount"    => 200,
    "status"    => "S"              
    }
    result = DBEngine.insert(COLLECTION_MAPREDUCE,document)
    puts result
    end
    2.times do |ctr|
    document = {
    "cust_id" => "A13",
    "amount"    => 250,
    "status"    => "S"
    }
    result = DBEngine.insert(COLLECTION_MAPREDUCE,document)
    puts result         
    end

    @map = "function(){" +
    "emit(this.cust_id,this.amount);" +
    "}; "
    @reduce = "function(key,values){" +
    "return Array.sum(values);" +
    "}"
    @query =    {
    :query => 
    {
    "status" => "S"
    }
    }           

    result = COLLECTION_MAPREDUCE.map_reduce(@map,@reduce,@query)
    puts result
    rescue Exception => e
    puts e
    end
    end
```

How to achieve this.I am new learner to ruby and mongodb.
Please help me.

Comment: There is no `last` in the portion of code you presented. You either need to show additional code or additional backtrace of the error.

Comment: I didn't get you ? what last part ?

Comment: i pasted that complete method.. and why downvote ?

Comment: @shan, The error message indicates that some code is calling the method `last` on a nil object.  The code you posted does not ever call the method `last` on any object.  It would be helpful to see at least the top few lines of the stack trace (with filenames and line numbers), and the actual code which is calling `last`.  Doing the research to find that code may be all that it takes for you to figure out the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason and my new code is

```
# Map function which emits the two necessary fileds like key and value to perform our operations
    map = "function(){" +
    "emit(this.cust_id,this.amount);" +
    "}; "

    # Reduce function reduces the values as per logic and outputs with key and value
    reduce = "function(key,values){" +
    "return Array.sum(values);" +
    "}"

    # Check this link fore reference :- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/master/Mongo/Collection:map_reduce
    # a customizable set of options to perform map reduce functions
    opts =  {
    :query => 
    {
    "status" => "S"
    },
    # out specifies where we need to output the map reduce output.
    # if we specify simply a name in string like "order_totals" it creates a collection in that name 
    # and stores in that
    # if we need to store in a temp memory and needed as output we need to give {:inline => 1} ans
    # :raw => true
    # check link :- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-cmd
    :out => {:inline => 1}, 
    :raw => true
    }           

    result = COLLECTION_MAPREDUCE.map_reduce(map,reduce,opts)
    result["results"].each do |obj|
    puts obj    
    puts "\n ------------"
    end
```

In opts i need to give the out and raw.i got fro the link
[here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/master/Mongo/Collection%3amap_reduce)

This code is working fine.
Thanks.